# Where is the localhost development datastore for gae java sdk/eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am testing my gae java jdo routines in eclipse.

The actual question is, how to clear/clean out the localhost development datastore so that I could start with a virgin datastore for a new cycle of tests?

Addional info - For those who don't know:
GAE = google app engine, google's "hosting solution" for java and python applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore

> The file is named local_db.bin, and it is created in your application's WAR directory, in the WEB-INF/appengine-generated/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a testing framework, for example, JUnit?  I have a @Before annotated method in my test classes and it runs before each @Test method, and the @Before method verifies that the local datastore is empty.  So for each test method it's verifying that it's emtpy and then reloading my test data.  I don't understand why you need to clear the local datastore.